# REORG TABLE seems to implicitly commit transaction

Tags: transactions, db2, db2-luw

I am testing a database migration that moves quite a lot of data around and also modifies the schema (changes to tables).

In DB2, whenever you alter a table, you need to call

```
CALL SYSPROC.ADMIN_CMD('REORG TABLE tablename');
```

otherwise, you cannot do anything with the table after.

For the test, I am running the migration in a single SQL transaction such that I can do a ROLLBACK at the end.

But it seems that the REORG TABLE command seems to implicity commit the transaction for that specific table. After I rollback, the schema of the tables on which I called REORG TABLE, have been persisted.

Am I missing something, or is testing migrations in a SQL transaction just not possible on DB2?

Comment: You don' need to run REORG after every ALTER TABLE. And you don't need to call ADMIN_CMD to invoke REORG. What do you want to do? What do you want to change/migrate?

Comment: Following this (http://db2commerce.com/2014/05/06/db2-basics-what-is-a-reorg/) I need to call reorg in my case, because I am adding columns (on new/existing tables) as nullable, moving data to them, than making them non-nullable and then dropping the old colums (in old tables).

Calling reorg without the ADMIN_CMD did not seem to work earlier but haven't tried again.

Comment: You should add the individual statements and where you have the transaction(s).

Answer (score 0):

DB2 reorg is a command (regardless of the method used to trigger it), and it has its own transaction control internally. So you cannot use ROLLBACK to undo the activities of reorg. Only SQL-statements and DDL are under transaction control.
If your intention is to back-out the activities of a reorg, or an entire migration, you might use a point-in-time restore, or perform the tests on disposable copy of the production database restored to a nonprod environment.

Comment: So, DML statements are not SQL? What about DDL statements -- they are under transaction control too?

Comment: Correction: only SQL and DDL are under transaction control in DB2 midrange, my typo.